# Difference between dataWithBytesNoCopy and dataWithBytes?

Tags: ios, byte, nsdata

What is the difference between

`+ (instancetype)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length;`

and

`+ (instancetype)dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length;`

Also,

`+ (instancetype)dataWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length freeWhenDone:(BOOL)b;`

if `b == YES`, will it free the bytes automatically after converted to data?

I am working on an app and almost finished it. But the last problem is it crashes with memory error when it runs on device. It only crashes when on device, but in simulator it is perfect.

```
"malloc: * error for object 0x17415d0c0: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list * set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug";
```

I have been working on this issue for several days:
[iOS - My app crashes with memory Error if only runs on Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320379/ios-my-app-crashes-with-memory-error-if-only-runs-on-device/30321772#30321772)

**But finally** I found the problem, inside my Encryption and Decryption function, I have this:

```
Byte *buffer    = (Byte*)malloc(asciiDataLength);
```

After I process with buffer, I convert it to `NSData`:

```
NSData *plainData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:asciiDataLength freeWhenDone:YES];
```

This code caused my app to crash continuously, I changed it to

```
NSData *plainData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:asciiDataLength];
free(buffer);
```

Then my app never crash again.

**So**, **I have to free the Byte by myself, ARC will not free it for me.**

Comment: One takes a copy of the data and the other doesn't.  What does the class reference tell you?  What is it specifically you don't understand?

Comment: OK.  Why use `malloc()` at all?  If you know the size of the buffer then use `NSMutableData` for all buffers and it will manage memory for you.  No copying either.

Comment: I have string to encrypt, I have to use XOR encryption, so I convert it to NSData, then get the bytes array, then make the XOR with the passPhrase, then convert it back to NSData, then get the string, send it to the server.

Comment: Sounds like you could get the string in an `NSMutableData` and apply the xor to that data and you're done? (unless you also need the original string).  The point is anything you can do with `malloc()` can also be done with `NSMutableData`.

Comment: I cannot make XOR to NSData directly, so I have to convert it to Byte array first. If you have have any idea apply XOR directly to the NSData, Can you guide me ? Thank you.

Comment: Convert it to `NSMutableData` with `[NSData mutableCopy]` or put the string into a `NSMutableData` object in the first place.

Comment: How you apply XOR to NSMutableData ?

Comment: The `mutableBytes` method returns the same data type that `malloc()` returns...

Comment: So in this way I do not have to manage the memory ? I have to check the NSMutableData Class Reference, thank you ^_^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`+ dataWithBytes:length:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytes:length:):

> Creates and returns a data object containing a given number of bytes **copied** from a given buffer.

[`+ dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:):

> Creates and returns a data object that holds length bytes **from the buffer `bytes`**.

`dataWithBytes` makes a copy of the buffer for the data, while the `NoCopy` version does not.

**Important note**: in the discussion section of `dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:`:

> The returned object takes ownership of the bytes pointer and **frees it on deallocation**. Therefore, **`bytes` must point to a memory block allocated with `malloc`**.

This means that initialising with this method essentially hands ownership of the memory to the `NSData` object, which will release it with `free` once it is done. If you try to initialise it with memory that you didn't allocate with `malloc`, your app will crash when the data object is deallocated.

`dataWithBytesNoCopy` is useful for when you get the bytes in a buffer from somewhere else, and are ready to hand them over to the `NSData` object, and won't use them yourself again outside of that.

If you want to initialise the data with memory you manage yourself, use [`+ dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:). This is useful if the buffer will be stored somewhere persistently, and not changed or released.

However, if you are not sure how to correctly manage this memory manually, it is better to use `dataWithBytes`. The other methods are present for performance reasons, as avoiding copying large chunks of data can save a lot of time, but if you aren't sure how to use them, it's probably best not to — an app that doesn't crash is preferable to an app that crashes quickly.

Comment: I decided to use NSData *plainData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:asciiDataLength];
free(buffer); Thank you ^_^

Comment: @UyghurBoy if this answered your question, please mark it as accepted with the tick button on the left.

Answer (score -1):

[[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:buflength] create a data object containing buflength bytes copied from the buffer bytes.

[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buflength] creates a data object that holds buflength bytes from the buffer bytes. The returned object takes ownership of the buffer pointer and frees it on deallocation. Therefore, buffer must point to a memory block allocated with malloc.